CUDA matrix transpose with shared mem
I am trying to incrementally optimize matrix transpose operation on CUDA and gain some hands on experience. I have tried a few things but the timing measurements that I am getting do not make sense. The idea is that reading a row and writing to a column output would be slow due to coalesced read but uncoalesced write. More efficient way should be uncoalesced read but coalesced write as reads might optimize on L1.
However, I am now trying to achieve both coalesced read and write.
The idea is to read from matrix in row major order and store the data without bank conflicts in shared memory. Then read from the shared memory in column major order, since my shared memory object is defined as int shared_mem[10][32], my assumption is that the reads should be broadcasted? Then use those column major shared memory read to write to the global memory in a row major fashion.
I am keeping things simplistic and my input/output matrices are multiples of 32. Furthermore in my "optimized" kernel I am not even so far concerned for correctness. All I am doing is reading from global memory in coalesced manner and writing to shared memory without bank conflicts. Yet, without even global memory write somehow I get same amount of cycles if I otherwise would write to global memory in my unoptimized kernel. Why is that? Is my idea of using shared memory meaningful? I have confirmed that my writes to shared memory do not have bank conflicts by padding shared memory and seeing multiple times worse cycle counts but how do I measure it differently? When I use nvprof I get 1 for min, max, avg shared_store_transacations_per_request regardless with padding and without which does not make sense cause padded one clearly, logically and time-wise has bank conflicts and is slower.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

// typedef unsigned int int;

#define CUDA_CHECK_ERROR() \
do { \
    cudaError_t err = cudaGetLastError(); \
    if (err != cudaSuccess) { \
        printf("CUDA error: %s at line %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(err), __LINE__); \
        exit(-1); \
    } \
} while (0)


#ifdef OPTIMIZED
__global__ void vector_transpose(int *in, int *out, int row, int col) {
    __shared__ int shared_mem[10][32];
    // padded __shared__ int shared_mem[10][32+1];

    int c = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    int r = blockDim.y * blockIdx.y + threadIdx.y;
    int idx = r * col + c;
    if (idx < row * col){
        int temp = in[idx]; 
        shared_mem[threadIdx.y][threadIdx.x] = temp;
    }
}
#else
__global__ void vector_transpose(int *in, int *out, int row, int col) {

    int c = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    int r = blockDim.y * blockIdx.y + threadIdx.y;

    if (r < row && c < col )
    {
            out[c * row + r] = in[r * col + c];
    } 
}
#endif

void printMatrix(int *matrix, int row, int col) {
    if (row * col > 30) return;
    for (int r = 0; r < row; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < col; c++) {
            printf("%d, ", matrix[r * col + c]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void UT_corret(int *h_org, int* h_transpose, int row, int col) {
    for (int r = 0; r < row; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < col; c++) {
            if (h_org[r * col + c] != h_transpose[c * row + r]) {
                printf("Not proper transpose\n");
                exit(2);
            }
        }
    }
    printf("****************Correct***************\n");
}


int main(){
    int *d_in, *d_out;
    int row = 12800;
    int col = 12800;
    int iter_num = 3;
    int size = row * col * sizeof(int);
    clock_t start, end, alloc_time;
    alloc_time = 0;
    int *h_org = (int *) malloc(size);
    int *h_transpose = (int *) malloc(size);
    if (h_org == NULL || h_transpose == NULL) {
        printf("Could not allocate enough memeory\n");
        exit(1);
    }


    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int r = 0; r < row; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < col; c++) {
            h_org[r * col + c] = rand() % 60;
        }
    }

#ifdef OS_CUDA
    start = clock();
    cudaMalloc(&d_in, size);
    CUDA_CHECK_ERROR();
    cudaMalloc(&d_out, size);
    CUDA_CHECK_ERROR();
    cudaMemcpy(d_in, h_org, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    CUDA_CHECK_ERROR();
    end = clock();
    alloc_time = end - start;
    dim3 threadsPerBlock(32, 10);
    dim3 numBlocks((row)/ threadsPerBlock.x + 1, (col) / threadsPerBlock.y + 1);
    printf("block x dimension: %d\n", numBlocks.x);
    printf("block y dimension: %d\n", numBlocks.y);
#endif
    printMatrix(h_org, row, col);

    start = clock();
#ifdef OS_CUDA
    vector_transpose<<<numBlocks, threadsPerBlock>>>(d_in, d_out, row, col);
    CUDA_CHECK_ERROR();
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    CUDA_CHECK_ERROR();
    for (int i = 0; i < iter_num; i++) {
        vector_transpose<<<numBlocks, threadsPerBlock>>>(d_in, d_out, row, col);
        CUDA_CHECK_ERROR();
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();
        CUDA_CHECK_ERROR();
    }
#else
    // CPU implementation goes here
#endif
    end = clock();
    printf("Execution time %ld  \n", (end - start) / iter_num);

#ifdef OS_CUDA
    start = clock();
    cudaMemcpy(h_transpose, d_out, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    end = clock();
    alloc_time += (end - start);
    printf("CUDA allocation time %ld    \n", alloc_time);
#endif
    printf("\n\n\n\nMatrix after transpose has been generated\n\n");
    printMatrix(h_org, col, row);

#ifdef OS_CUDA
    UT_corret(h_org, h_transpose, row, col);
#endif

    return 0;
}

This is how I compile and  run nvprof + output for both padded and non padded is same:
nvcc -O0 -Xcicc -O0 -Xptxas -O0  -DOS_CUDA   -DOPTIMIZED helloworld.cu  && sudo nvprof --metrics shared_load_transactions_per_request,shared_store_transactions_per_request ./a.out 
helloworld.cu(20): warning #550-D: variable "shared_mem" was set but never used

==84333== NVPROF is profiling process 84333, command: ./a.out
block x dimension: 401
block y dimension: 1281
==84333== Some kernel(s) will be replayed on device 0 in order to collect all events/metrics.
Replaying kernel "vector_transpose(int*, int*, int, int)" (done)
Replaying kernel "vector_transpose(int*, int*, int, int)" (done)
Replaying kernel "vector_transpose(int*, int*, int, int)" (done)
Replaying kernel "vector_transpose(int*, int*, int, int)" (2 of 2)... 
Replaying kernel "vector_transpose(int*, int*, int, int)" (done)
CUDA allocation time 655451    


Execution time 1500245  

Matrix after transpose has been generated

Not proper transpose
==84333== Profiling application: ./a.out
==84333== Profiling result:
==84333== Metric result:
Invocations                               Metric Name                             Metric Description         Min         Max         Avg
Device "NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 (0)"
    Kernel: vector_transpose(int*, int*, int, int)
          4      shared_load_transactions_per_request    Shared Memory Load Transactions Per Request    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
          4     shared_store_transactions_per_request   Shared Memory Store Transactions Per Request    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000

This is the output of running optimized:
nvcc -O0 -Xcicc -O0 -Xptxas -O0  -DOS_CUDA   -DOPTIMIZED helloworld.cu  && ./a.out 
helloworld.cu(20): warning #550-D: variable "shared_mem" was set but never used

block x dimension: 401
block y dimension: 1281
Execution time 83242  
CUDA allocation time 532131    




Matrix after transpose has been generated

Not proper transpose

and the output of running non-optimized:
nvcc -O0 -Xcicc -O0 -Xptxas -O0  -DOS_CUDA   helloworld.cu  && ./a.out 
block x dimension: 401
block y dimension: 1281
Execution time 80694  
CUDA allocation time 521656    




Matrix after transpose has been generated

****************Correct***************```

I have been compiling and running on 1050 mobile.

The way you are writing to shared memory in row-major fashion is bank-conflict free independent of the padding. The padding only plays a role when you read from shared memory in column-major fashion. So the profiler output looks as expected to me.

Not sure what you mean by "my assumption is that the reads should be broadcasted?". No value should be read twice, so why should anything be broadcasted here?

Note that Nvidia provides a sample code for exactly this operation: Samples/6_Performance/transpose. Sadly Nvidia did not modernize this sample for recent architectures, so it still contains easily avoidable shared memory bank conflicts. At least one only needs to change two preprocessor constants (See my issue).
